# plot3 for display three dimension data in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

i want using plot3 for display three dimension data. size of data is (400*3) that contain two class. size of class A is 300 and size of class  B is 100. 
but after run this code  z axis is not showing.
please guide me.

```
Fspace = rand(400,3);
figure;hold on;
plot3(Fspace(1:300,1),Fspace(1:300,2),Fspace(1:300,3),'b*');
plot3(Fspace(301:400,1),Fspace(301:400,2),Fspace(301:400,3),'ro');
legend('Class A','Class B');
% axis equal;
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
zlabel('z');
title('original data');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the z-axis is there, you're just looking from the top down. 
add `view(3)` to the end of your code to change the viewpoint to the default 3d viewpoint (no idea why it's not like that by default)